# Помогите расставить знаки препинания (4)

Tags: пунктуация

Не могу понять: либо здесь много двоеточий, либо здесь много точек.

(Знаки препинания не расставлены.)

> Специалисты Иван Фёдорович направления биология физика Борис
>   Николаевич направления математика физика Пётр Тимофеевич направления
>   информатика математика.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать **скобки** (внутри них вместо двоеточия — тире).

Специалисты: Иван Фёдорович (направления — биология, физика), Борис Николаевич (направления — математика, физика), Пётр Тимофеевич (направления — информатика, математика).

Можно оформить **списком** (но тогда уже лучше без слова "направление).

Специалисты:
Иван Фёдорович (биология, физика);
Борис Николаевич (математика, физика);
Пётр Тимофеевич (информатика, математика).

Answer (score 1):

В качестве варианта:

***Специалисты***: Иван Фёдорович, направления биология, физика; Борис Николаевич, направления математика, физика; Пётр Тимофеевич, направления информатика, математика.

Comment: Мне помогли оба ответа, поэтому я отдал вам один голос.

Comment: Спасибо. Правда, у меня вопрос. В скобках нужно использовать Р.п., а не И.п.?